# Scala multiple query params, but exactly one is required

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have to implement a GET where I can have 5 different query params but the request is valid only if just one parameter is passed.
I'm new to Scala world. What would be the best approach?

Currently I was using parameterMap but I am open to suggestions.

```
pathPrefix("cars") {
  pathSingleSlash {
    complete("/engines")
  }
  get {
    parameterMap { params =>
      if (params.size != 1) {
        complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest)
      } else {

        params.foreach{
          case ("asd", value ) //doSomething
          case _ => complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest)

        }
     }
  }
}
```

This isnt currenly working because:

```
 Error:(39, 27) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]
            params.foreach{
```

I can solve it by adding a complete at the end, but that is not the solution.
Any suggestions?

Valid requests

```
/app/cars/engines?capacity=1000
/app/cars/engines?type=benzin
```

Invalid request

```
/app/cars/engines?type=benzin&capacity=1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Your overall approach is fine, notwithstanding the "type mismatch" error. The cause of that error is the use of `foreach`, which returns a `Unit`. A way to fix the error is to inspect the `head` of the `Map` after checking that the size of the `Map` is one:

```
get {
  parameterMap { params =>
    if (params.size != 1) {
      complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest)
    } else {
      params.head match {
        case ("asd", value) =>
          // do something
          complete(StatusCodes.OK)
        case _ =>
          complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked and makes sense.
But now I'm thinking that I my business logic should return a Future of something so I would need an onSucces(result) for every case. I guess I dont even need a foreach, since there I will have only one pair (key, value) and I can call a service with that pair

Comment: I'm sorry, I havent seen u removed foreach. My problem now is that I somehow need to validate the parameters. I need exactly one, but one valid

Comment: You can add if condition to the pattern match like `case ("asd", value) if validate(value)` , where validate method will validate the param and return a boolean